# Linking Rust to LLVM API in Cargo.toml

Tags: rust, linker, llvm, rust-cargo

I'm using a library that wraps the LLVM-C API (inkwell) so I need to link my Rust binary to the LLVM library. If I export the following rust flags with:

```sh
export RUSTFLAGS=-lLLVM-12 -lm -ldl -lc -lpthread -lutil -lgcc_s -C link-args=-L/usr/lib/llvm/12/lib64
```

Then compilation runs fine.

If I then insert these lines into my `Cargo.toml` file for the project however:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-lLLVM-12", "-lm","-ldl","-lc","-lpthread","-lutil","-lgcc_s", "-C", "link-args=-L/usr/lib/llvm/12/lib64"]
```

Then I get linking errors against LLVM-C functions.

Why does this work with an environment variable but not in my cargo config file? Am I msiconfiguring cargo in some way?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but AFAIK rustflags are configured via `config.toml`, not `Cargo.toml` - https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html

Comment: This solved it, thanks. You can add a reply for me to mark as solved if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Cargo documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html), `rustflags` property is documented via `.cargo/config.toml`, not `Cargo.toml`.